# downgrade laravel project 5.5 to 5.0.*

Tags: php, laravel, downgrade, composer-php

First of all sorry about my English! I'm in situation where I need to downgrade my Laravel project because some history about php version running on installation server (php 5.4). After I set my composer.json and run update,
I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYfvV.jpg)

```
composer update --no-interaction --ansi
 C:\composer\composer.bat update --no-interaction --ansi
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
 Package operations: 46 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
   - Installing psy/psysh (v0.4.4): Downloading (connecting...)
 Downloading (failed)
 Downloading (connecting...)
 Downloading (failed)
 Downloading (connecting...)
 Downloading (failed)    Failed to download psy/psysh from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/bobthecow/psysh/zipball/489816db71649bd95b416e3ed9062d40528ab0ac" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
 error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
 Failed to enable crypto
 failed to open stream: operation failed
     Now trying to download from source
   - Installing psy/psysh (v0.4.4): Cloning 489816db71 from cache
     489816db71649bd95b416e3ed9062d40528ab0ac is gone (history was rewritten?)
 
 
   [RuntimeException]
   Failed to execute git checkout "489816db71649bd95b416e3ed9062d40528ab0ac" -
   - && git reset --hard "489816db71649bd95b416e3ed9062d40528ab0ac" --
 
   fatal: reference is not a tree: 489816db71649bd95b416e3ed9062d40528ab0ac
 
 
 update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
 
 Failed to update packages for  ./composer.json.
```

could someone help me to fix this error?!

Comment: Isn't easier to update to a faster, more secure and reliable PHP version?

Comment: There are so many differences between Laravel 5.5 and Laravel 5.0 including directory structures, you won't be able to just reinstall the vendor packages.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte you're right, i thought like this but the infrastructure guys of my  company dicided to keep the version of php on server (php 5.4) because it's running some project there right now, and downgrade the php version of project (php 7.1.3 to 5.4)

Comment: Ahh, the old fight between developers and infra. Good luck there. I would advice you to talk to some manager and explain why it will be more expensive to downgrade, because you will have to refactor and re-test the entire application.

Comment: what i can do in this case?!

Comment: you can use multiple php versions side by side... so install php 7 as well on your server

Comment: @HamidAli it is possible?!

Comment: yes it is possible i am running some applications on php 5.6 and some on php 7.1.* on production server...

Comment: by the way i am using plesk onyx for managing my server...

Comment: if you know about production stack of your server it might help alot